# error as.formula function: attempt to set an attribute on NULL

Tags: r, neural-network, formula

A quick question:

I'm building a NN model and I don't want to type in all the variables. Instead I'd like to save a variable with some of the col names and use it int he formula.

When I'm approaching it in this way, this code gives me an error.

Why and how can I fix it?

```
labels <- paste('label',seq(1,8,1), sep='', collapse = ' + ')

labels <- paste(labels,'+','label9')

labels <- as.formula(labels)

Error in class(ff) <- "formula" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

What I need to get is label1 + label2 + label3 + label4 + label5 + label6 + label7 + label8 + label9 as a formula.

Answer (score 2):

We may use `paste` with `~`

```
as.formula(paste0(labels, "~ ."))
label1 + label2 + label3 + label4 + label5 + label6 + label7 + 
    label8 + label9 ~ .
```

---

Or with `reformulate`

```
 reformulate(response = labels, ".")
label1 + label2 + label3 + label4 + label5 + label6 + label7 + 
    label8 + label9 ~ .
```

Comment: The problem is that these are the dependent vars or nodes, so the '~' should go after them. And if I paste it after the vars, I still get an error :Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: label1 + label2 + label3 + label4 + label5 + label6 + label7 + label8~

Comment: the first one worked to create the formula but then gave an error in the model, the second gave an error :labels <- reformulate(response = labels, ".")
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"labels <- (paste(labels,'+','label9')
labels"

The error of the first code in the model:

nn <- neuralnet(labels ~ .,
+                data = data_train, 
+                act.fct = 'logistic',  # use sigmoig function
+                 linear.output = F)
Error in model.frame.default(as.formula(call("~", formula[[2]])), data) : 
  object is not a matrix

Comment: @tensai Sorry, your question is not reproducible as we don't know your model or what you are trying to do

Comment: well, I just added it in the comment

Comment: @tensai i guess the second may have given error because you have already assigned `labels <-` to the formula object

Comment: @tensai well, it is not reproducible.  I used the same code, it says `data_train` is not found

Comment: The error also says something about the data.  ie. it is expecting a matrix, but the data is not matrix.  Without reproducible example, you can't expect others to test

Comment: I have worked a bit further on it and at the end it worked! Your code totally helped, thank you!